# How to add my element in Qt Vertical layout from top to bottom?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlayout

I need to add widgets from top to bottom, actually when I add new widget it is adding it automatically to bottom.

```
self.chartLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
for (adding graph each loop)
    self.chartLayout.addWidget(self.chartVs[lastIndex])
```

At the end I have, something like :

```
Graph1
Graph2
...
Graphx
```

I need to have :

```
Graphx
..
Graph2
Graph1
```

Comment: Can try to use insertWidget with index 0. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget.

Comment: Pham, yes that works you are the best. 
I now I need to get the index of the inserted widgets, do you know a quick function?

Comment: You can get QLayoutItem with 'itemAt(int index)' then call 'widget()' to get inserted QWidget. Be careful, because qlayout can add qspacer instead of qwidget. Another way is to store widgets and their indies to a map.